# Where do submit_tags submit to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that doesn't have an action explicitly list the action that it hits when it gets submitted. It uses `form_tag`and `submit_tag`. Where might I start looking to see what end point it hits?

Comment: unless you explicitly give the form a url and or action rails will use default behavior where possible. What this endpoint is by default depends on the view where the form is rendered...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the rails routing system. Where it submits to depends on rails default behavior if you do not give any other options or methods to the form.

```
new => #create via 'POST'
edit => #update with via 'PATCH/PUT'
```

etc...

Have a look here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the url with the HTTP method as defined in your application routes on your `form_tag` which is the submission endpoint that the form is submitted to by the `submit_tag`

```
<%= form_tag('/search', method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, '', placeholder: 'Search here' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/search' => "pages#search"
```

In this example, when you submit the form, it hits `PagesController#search` action with the value typed in input field as `params[:query]`